# C# Soft Number By Difference From Input

Tags: c#, console-application

I have the following code. Please help me get my desired output. I have a list of numbers then I have input value which is 4. I want that my list will be sorted based on 0 difference first then the rest will be ascending. For example in my list there are 4s. My input is 4 so I want to sort those numbers where number item - input value=0 (4-4=0).

**C#**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 1, 4 };
        var sortedNumbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x - 4 == 0);
        foreach (var item in sortedNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
1
4
4
4
4
```

**Desired Output**

```
4
4
4
4
1
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: `I want that my list will be sorted based on 0 difference first then the rest will be ascending.`  Can you elaborate?  What does this mean?

Comment: @Amy for example in the list of numbers there are 4s. My input is 4 so I want to get all items first by zero difference for example *4(from the list item)-4(input)=0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output by using a ternary expression inside the `OrderBy` lambda :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 1, 4 };
        var sortedNumbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x==4? int.MinValue: x);
        foreach (var item in sortedNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

output :

```
4
4
4
4
1
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
```

Edit : in case you have zero or negative number in your list, your number will be order as follow : first, exact match, then ascending. For example : `{ -1, 0, 0, -12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 1, 4 }`

the result will be the following :

```
4
4
4
4
-12
-1
0
0
1
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: This would put negative numbers first, then "zero and four" values, then everything else. It would work for the sample input, but I see nothing in the question that guarantees the list won't contain zeroes or negative numbers.

Comment: This will still do the wrong thing if the input contains `int.MinValue`. Rather than using a magic value, it's better to use the *actual predicate* (whether or not it's equal) rather than mapping to another value.

Comment: @JonSkeet I considered unlikely to have `int.MinValue` in the list, but you're right. The problem with the predicate is it only returns `true` or `false`so the solution is either to pre-sort the list, or to use a second predicate `ThenBy`(like Tim Schmelter.did)

Comment: And to my mind, using a second ordering is a much better solution, because it more directly maps to the original problem statement: "I want that my list will be sorted based on 0 difference first **then** the rest will be ascending." When the problem description is in terms of a two-stage ordering, it feels natural that the solution should be too.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `numbers.OrderBy(x => x - 4 == 0)` you need to use `OrderByDescending`, because true is "more" than false and you want them first. You also want to sort the rest by their value:

```
var sortedNumbers = numbers.OrderByDescending(x => x == 4).ThenBy(x => x);
```

If you can't remember if you need to use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` use:

```
var sortedNumbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x == 4 ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(x => x);
```

Comment: I'd also suggest using `x == 4` as a simpler way of checking whether a value is 4 than `x - 4 == 0`. (And instead of using `OrderByDescending`, you could use `OrderByDescending(x => x != 4)`, although I'm not sure that's clearer...)

Comment: When you're using `numbers.OrderBy(x => x == 4 ? 0 : 1)`, the numbers other than 4 are not ordered ascendingly (they keep their initial order in the list). So your first option is better.

Comment: @XouDo: Sure, the second way was just tellling OP how to prevent the `OrderBy(bool)` with easier `OrderBy(int)`. Then he doesn't need to remember whether to use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` with a `bool`. Of course he needs to append the `ThenBy(x => x)` too. I will edit it, thought it was clear. Edit: Done